# No funcionan mis operaciones DELETE ni PUT de SpringBoot

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, backend

estoy realizando un proyecto en SpringBoot* y el código que tengo a continuación me devuelve siempre un 404 en el Postman cuando mando un DELETE a "localhost:8080/delete/1" o un PUT "localhost:8080/actualizar/1". Existe en la tabla "usuario" el usuarioid 1, lo puedo ver cuando envío un GET a "localhost:8080/usuario/buscar". La idea de "/actualizar/{usuarioid}" es sumarle 1 al valor de "editable" en la base de datos. Les dejo a continuación la DB y el servicio de SpringBoot:

usuarioid es Integer NOT NULL y PK (al crearlo puse usuarioid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY para que sea autoincrementable). "correo", "nombre" y "password" son VARCHAR(45), y editable es Integer.

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/usuario")
@CrossOrigin
public class UsuarioService {

    @Autowired
    UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    @GetMapping ( path = "/buscar" )
    public List <Usuario> GetAllUsuario(){
        return usuarioRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping ( path = "/guardar" )
    public Usuario saveUsuario(@RequestBody Usuario usuario) {
        usuario.setEditable(45);
        return usuarioRepository.save(usuario);
    }

    @DeleteMapping ( path = "/eliminar/{usuarioid}" )
    public void deleteUsuario(@PathVariable ("usuarioid") Integer usuarioid) {
        Optional <Usuario> usuario;
        usuario = usuarioRepository.findById(usuarioid);
        if(usuario.isPresent()){
            usuarioRepository.delete(usuario.get());
        }
    }

    @PostMapping ( path = "/login")
    public Usuario login(@RequestBody Usuario usuario){
    
        List<Usuario> usuarios = usuarioRepository.findByCorreoAndPassword(usuario.getCorreo(), usuario.getPassword());
    
        if(!usuarios.isEmpty()) {
            return usuarios.get(0);
        }
    
        return null;
    }

    @PutMapping ( path = "/actualizar/{usuarioid}" )
    public ResponseEntity<Usuario> updateUsuario(@PathVariable("usuarioid") Integer usuarioid, @RequestBody Usuario usuario){
        Optional<Usuario> usuarioDb = usuarioRepository.findById(usuarioid);
        if(usuarioDb.isPresent()){
            Usuario usuarioUpdate = usuarioDb.get();
            usuarioUpdate.setEditable(usuarioUpdate.getEditable() + 1);
            usuarioRepository.save(usuarioUpdate);
            return new ResponseEntity<Usuario>(usuarioUpdate, HttpStatus.OK);
        }else{
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
}
```

Por supuesto, todas las importaciones las salteo porque son innecesarias acá. Todo lo demás funciona perfecto menos esos 2 que mencioné.

Comment: Todos estos endpoints deben empezar con localhost:8080/usuario. Tal vez es un typo en tu pregunta, pero prueba enviando un PUT a localhost:8080/usuario/actualizar/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia esto:

```
return new ResponseEntity<Usuario>(usuarioUpdate, HttpStatus.OK);
```

A esto:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(usuarioUpdate);
```

Y esto:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

A esto:

```
return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
```

---

Y considera:

- `usuarioDb` puede cumplir la función de `usuarioUpdate`, no requieres esta segunda instancia de Usuario.
- Y es ideal entre el repositorio y el Controller meterle un service de `class` con `interface`, para desacoplar el código.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Veo 2 problemas en la manera en que intentas actualizar/eliminar al usuario. El `404 Not Found` no se debe a que no encuentra el usuario, si no a que no encuentra los end-points.
Comentas lo siguiente:

> mando un DELETE a "localhost:8080/delete/1" o un PUT
> "localhost:8080/actualizar/1"

Sin embargo, en el controlador, puede verse que el path principal depende de '*/usuario*'. Además, tu método `DELETE` se llama '*/eliminar*'.

La solución está en que realices esas dos llamadas de la siguiente manera:

- ***localhost:8080/usuario/eliminar/1***
- ***localhost:8080/usuario/actualizar/1***